# How can I utilize Oracle bind variables with Delphi's SimpleDataSet?

Tags: oracle, delphi, dbexpress

I have an Oracle 9 database from which my Delphi 2006 application reads data into a `TSimpleDataSet` using a SQL statement like this one (in reality it is more complex, of course):

```
select * from myschema.mytable where ID in (1, 2, 4)
```

My applications starts up and executes this query quite often during the course of the day, each time with different values in the `in` clause.

My DBAs have notified me that this is creating execessive load on the database server, as the query is re-parsed on every run. They suggested to use [bind variables](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/LiteralsSubstitutionVariablesAndBindVariables.php#bind_variables) instead of building the SQL statement on the client.

I am familiar with using parameterized queries in Delphi, but from the article linked to above I get the feeling that is not exactly what bind variables are. Also, I would need theses prepared statements to work across different runs of the application.

Is there a way to prepare a statement containing an `in` clause once in the database and then have it executed with different parameters passed in from a `TSimpleDataSet` so it won't need to be reparsed every time my application is run?

Comment: Are you sure you really need to use TSimpleDataSet or dbExpress? It seems if performance matters maybe you should be switching to native Oracle-only DB components and dropping dbExpress and TSimpleDataSet?

Comment: @WarrenP If at all possible I would like to stay with dbExpress as I have a whole bunch of other components build around it. Just out of curiosity, though, what native Oracle-only DB components did you have in mind?

Comment: commercial and very high performance: http://www.devart.com/odac/

Comment: Commercial, and I highly recommend [Direct Oracle Access](http://www.allroundautomations.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is not directly related to Delphi, but this problem in general. Your problem is that of the variable-sized in-list. [Tom Kyte of Oracle](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html) has some recommendations which you can use. Essentially, you are creating too many unique queries, causing the database to do a bunch of hard-parsing. This will spike the CPU consumption (and DBA blood pressures) unnecessarily.

By making your query static, it can get by with a soft-parse or perhaps no parse at all! The DB can then cache the execution plan, the DBAs can deal with a more "stable" SQL, and overall performance should be improved.